# C# Generic and Derivation

Tags: c#, generics, derived-class

I've been digging through several posts on this subject and could not find any suitable answer to the following problem…

can anyone tell me why this does not compile :

```
class MyItem {
    public int ID;
}
class MyList<T> {
    public List<T> ItemList;
}


class MyDerivedItem : MyItem {
    public string Name;
}
class MyDerivedList<MyDerivedItem> : MyList<MyDerivedItem> {
    public int GetID(int index) {
        return ItemList[index].ID; // ERROR : MyDerivedItem does not contain a definition for ID
    }
    public string GetName(int index) {
        return ItemList[index].Name; // ERROR : MyDerivedItem does not contain a definition for Name
    }
}
```

Comment: **[Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)**

Comment: corrected the "public" typos. Was obviously not what the compiler was complaining about...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues with this, this first of which is your generic signature.

While `class MyDerivedList<MyDerivedItem> : MyList<MyDerivedItem>` may seem like a generic class declaration using `MyDerivedItem` as the type, you've really just declared a generic class that uses `MyDerivedItem` as the name of the generic type argument.

What you're looking for is `class MyDerivedList<T> : MyList<T> where T : MyDerivedItem`, which will exchange your first problem for your next one, which is that the properties of your other types are not accessible enough for this one.

```
class MyItem
{
    public int ID;
}
class MyList<T>
{
    public List<T> ItemList;
}

class MyDerivedItem : MyItem
{
    public string Name;
}
```

Okay, now the properties are accessible enough to be accessed from the `MyDerivedList` class, but there's one last issue to correct. `int GetName(int index)` should be `string GetName(int index)`, as the `Name` property is a string.

This results in the following:

```
class MyDerivedList<T> : MyList<T> where T : MyDerivedItem
{
    int GetID(int index)
    {
        return ItemList[index].ID;
    }
    string GetName(int index)
    {
        return ItemList[index].Name; 
    }
}
```

Which should compile just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Jonathon's answer is correct but maybe the proposed solution is not exactly what you want.

Maybe you simply want a non generic type that inherits a closed generic type:

```
class MyDerivedList : MyList<MyDerivedItem>
```

And now your code will work as expected:

```
 class MyDerivedList : MyList<MyDerivedItem>
 {
    int GetID(int index)
    {
        return ItemList[index].ID;
    }

    string GetName(int index)
    {
        return ItemList[index].Name; 
    }
}
```

Contrary to your attempt, in the code above `MyDerivedItem` really is the type `MyDerivedItem` and not a generic type parameter of the generic class `MyDerivedList<>`.

Confusing? Yes, that is why you should avoid naming generic type parameters with type names, it can make your head hurt; your code and the following are exactly the same:

```
class MyDerivedList<T> : MyList<T>
```

But now the fact that `T` is a generic type parameter and not a concrete type is obvious.

Comment: Thanks for this alternative but Johnaton's answer was really what I wanted to achieve.